# (VCA - VGA) Design of an amplifier controlled by a ramp

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing

I would like to design a circuit with an AOP which will have a variable gain controlled by a tension (a ramp). Could you help me and explain me the circuit please?

Thank you,

Farad

Comment: It is called a multiplier. It is also called a Variable Gain Amplifier (VGA). Go forth and Google.

Comment: This is unrelated to this question but, Dave Tweed and I answered this question a while back - did you not understand the answers: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209607/envelope-detector

Comment: WhatRoughBeast as you see on the title I know it is a VGA... Google show me some circuit but It don't do what I want... 
Thank you Andy, I forgot to answer.. I will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interrested by the answer. I used a multiplier as a VGA. In order to create this function I used :

- 2x Log amplifier
- 1x sum amplifier
- 1x Exp amplifier

If I want multiply a signal V1 with a signal V2 =>

exp(log(V1)+log(V2)) = V1 * V2

The following figure is the result :
[image]

Comment: Please note that that will only work as a first-quadrant amplifier. That is, both inputs must be positive, so showing V1 as an AC signal is misleading. Second, it's not a very good amplifier, without much bandwidth or dynamic range. It may be good enough for your (unstated) purpose, but it may not.