# Envelope detector and DC voltage

Tags: simulation, detector, amplitude

I am currently working in the simulation of a physics project. One of the detectors inputs a voltage V1:

V1(t)= D+A*cos(w*t)

[image]

and tries to extract the amplitude. I read that a simple  [Envelope detector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209607/envelope-detector) can do the job. The problem is that in my system sometimes D takes really big values and then the detector fails and returns a wrong value. I have very little idea on how to use a circuit in which this doesn't happen, although I guess that a high pass filter before the source could solve the problem.

How do I stop by system from failing to detect and return the wrong value?

Comment: "_One of the detectors inputs a voltage current_", so it inputs power?

Comment: Eliminate D and use Cs = k*C1 where k is your bandwidth ratio from max to min.

Comment: Put that into an answer @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, it looks like it's better than my answer if you put some meat to the bones.

Comment: What? I dont understand, could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @Victor That's exactly why I want him to turn it into an answer so he can elaborate.

Comment: OK Harry but Victor please define Signal ( AC pp , fmin, fmax, ) Noise (Vdc, f ) then load + source impedance.  or define exactly what you need to recover. Until then...

Answer (score 1):

Using a RC high pass filter to get rid of the DC component is the way to go. And that is the **easiest solution**. Just two components.

Why do you want other solutions? Or rather, what kind of *other* solutions do you want / expect?

Comment: Thanks! I wanted a circuit that worked with the least number of differential equations, as I only need to simulate the system connected to a bigger project. But i guess this is ok.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need differential equations to solve a DC blocking HPF with a rectifier.

### First the HPF , LPF response.

- The low frequency cutoff affects the step response time Ts and its associated frequency response where  ω=1/T. and adding a series cap, Cs, with some known source impedance Rs and parallel load resistance, Rp then

  - Ts= (Rs+Rp)Cs
- The high frequency cutoff or low pass filter LPF has the same equation for ω=1/T and parallel load cap Cp, Rp gives

  - Tp= (Rs+Rp)Cp

Now if you used matched R source and load eg 50 ohms then midband loss is -6dB and breakpoints occur at -9dB (3dB down) then your bandwidth ratio or its inverse  T ratio is Cs/Cp . e.g. for 3 decades of response Cs=1000Cp

If anyone sees a mistake, pls let me know otherwise if Ok pls upvote your concurrence.